# I got error while run my code in python2.7 how to fix that error?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\1.wedding.py", line 28, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: newsflash: "'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH." download it and put it in your path.

Comment: @flyfire I've rolled back your post. Please learn how to format code within your posts and don't delete relevant information that you've previously provided (namely, the traceback information).

Comment: now everything was fine thanks Possible duplicate of Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH – MYG

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved . i just installed geckodriver.exe from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases